# OpenCV cv::Mat size limit

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

When I setting a cv::Mat object with large width and height, the code would run exception... or print "bgModel.size != tsize."
And when I lower width or height, print "bgModel.size == tsize."
It seems that cv::Mat has a size limitation.
Is there any method that can modify limitations?

software info. : windows 10 OS, Visual Studio 2015, OpenCV 2.4.13.5
hardware info. : i7-9700 CPU, 64GB Ram.

The C++ Code below:

```
int main()
{
    int nWidth = 13529;
    int nHeight = 10198;

    unsigned long long int tSize = static_cast<long long int>(nWidth)*static_cast<long long int>(nHeight)*static_cast<long long int>(25);
    
    try
    {
        cv::Mat bgModel;
        bgModel.create(1, nHeight*nWidth*25, CV_32F);
        
        if (bgModel.cols*bgModel.rows == tSize)
        {
            cout << "bgModel.size == tsize" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "bgModel.size != tsize" << endl;
        }

        bgModel.release();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        cout << "thrown exception...." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah, the issue is that cv::Mat constructors and functions like `create` take in `int` as the type for width/height. So you're limited by the API.

Comment: @PeterT I really don't call it API limitation really. it is 2147483647 for each dimension of Mat..... I think it is more case of trying to implement an idea without optimizing.

Comment: You might think the limitation is reasonable, I would've thought so too in the year 2000. Doesn't change the fact that it's a limitation.

Comment: @PeterT but we should consider that opencv in for image processing, and this limit covers almost any type of normal image.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you need such huge `cv::Mat`, but its size is at least **12GB**!!! So this code will not work if your code is compiled to 32-bit binary. I'm pretty sure that your exception comes from memory limits.

**And finally:** `bgModel.cols` and `bgModel.rows` are `int`, if you multiply them it will overflow and your calculation will be incorrect. so you need to cast it like you have done for `tSize`.

Another problem is that `create()` method is defined like this:

```
void cv::Mat::create(int rows, int cols, int type)
```

and as you see `int` data type range for `cols` cannot handle `nHeight*nWidth*25` which is `3,449,218,550`. Max `int` can handle is `2,147,483,647`.

Comment: Even I try bgModel.create(nWidth*5, nHeight*5, CV_32F), the rows and cols are in range of int. It also not feasible....
Maybe I should think another method to handle such large data, not to use only one cv::Mat.

Comment: @AlennexCheng You should consider trying not to load whole data in memory first if you can.